# Center Aligning the Page Content

Tags: html

Forgive me for asking this silly question as I am a newbie to HTML.

I am trying to place some image based stuff in the center of the page. So, when we write,

```html
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
      
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the content becomes left aligned (i.e., from column 1 to 6). How to exactly take it to the center? Do we need to leave 3 columns from both left and right to bring to the center, and if so, how to go about it?

Comment: where is your html code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add helpful info.

Comment: I have added a broad chunk of HTML Code I am following

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with `bootstrap` to make `grid view of your page`

```css
  .row div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center"><img src="http://publish.illinois.edu/engineeringcareerservices-new/files/2014/08/UI-02-140808-014.jpg" width="100" height="100"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have posted my version of a broader code by editing the Question.

Comment: add `<div class="col-sm-3"></div>` div before and after your `div` so its work @Qureshi

Comment: in my answer its work perfectly. what was the issue with my answer?@Qureshi

Comment: Thank you. I just added <div class="col-sm-3"></div> before my <div>and it worked perfectly. Perhaps, I don't need to add it after my <div>, i.e., 3 columns + 6 columns = 9 columns and remaining 3 would be on the right side by default, which makes the content centralized.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS for make something center. you can read more about CSS [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) and you can use in this way to make your text center.

```
 <style>
 .col-sm-6 {
    text-align: center;
     } 
</style>
```

alse you can find other method of CSS style [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you make an element a pixel width (e.g width:100px) then you can also add margin:auto which will centre align it within it's parent element